# Aggregating by unique identifier and put unique values into a string

Tags: r

I have a need that I imagine could be satisfied by `aggregate` or `reshape`, but I can't quite figure out.

I have a list of names with the color of the car that own each person. This data is in long form, so names can have multiple colours. I'd like to fuse by the name and get the max colour.

For example,

```
Name    car_colour 
Euler       blue
Gauss       red
Hilbert     white
Hilbert     green
Knuth       yellow
Knuth       orange
Knuth       cyan
Knuth       violet
Knuth       darkblue
```

Would become...

```
Name        car_color 
Euler       blue
Gauss       red
Hilbert     green
Knuth       cyan
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: While you were trying to figure it out, what did you try?  Please post the code and show where it went wrong.

Comment: Excuse my laziness (or maybe that was very obfuscated a while ago) but I found the solution. It was very simple ...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys but the answer was very simple:

```
> Name=c('Euler','Gauss','Hilbert','Hilbert','Knuth','Knuth','Knuth','Knuth','Knuth')
> car_colour=c('blue','red','white','green','yellow','orange','cyan','violet','darkblue')
> nc=as.data.frame(cbind(Name,car_colour))
> nc
     Name car_colour
1   Euler       blue
2   Gauss        red
3 Hilbert      white
4 Hilbert      green
5   Knuth     yellow
6   Knuth     orange
7   Knuth       cyan
8   Knuth     violet
9   Knuth   darkblue
> nc.agg <- aggregate( as.character(car_colour) ~ Name, nc, FUN = "min")
> nc.agg
     Name as.character(car_colour)
1   Euler                     blue
2   Gauss                      red
3 Hilbert                    green
4   Knuth                     cyan
```

Comment: Don't get in the habit of doing `data.frame(cbind(...))` - use `data.frame(Name,car_colour)` directly or otherwise all your numeric data can end being forced to character data. Also, if you specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when doing `data.frame()`, you can skip the `as.character()`

Answer (score 0):

Quick, **super awful** method!

I made an example called test.

```
test
letter color   
[1,] "a"    "blue"  
[2,] "a"    "red"   
[3,] "a"    "red"   
[4,] "b"    "orange"
[5,] "c"    "green" 


testTable=table(test[,1], test[,2])
testNames=colnames(testTable)[apply(testTable,1,which.max)]
testOut=data.frame(letter=unique(test[,1]), color=testNames)
```

I'm thinking someone else might have a less silly way to get to the same answer. I'll happily upvote someone who one-liners it!